# Async Read Synchronization

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, synchronization

It seems that I can not find an elegant solution for a synchronization of the code below. I remember that once I did the similar thing but currently my mind is blank.

I need to protect that no two threads will read from the socket, that always be only one thread that waits on BeginRead. When I use Mutex in this way, I get SyncronizationError.

```
class Program
{
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    public readonly object loker = new object();

    public void BeginRead()
    {
        if (!Mutex.TryEnter(loker))
        {
            return;
        }
        client.GetStream().BeginRead(..., Read_Callback);
    }

    private void Read_Callback(IAsyncResult ar) 
    {
        client.GetStream().EndRead(ar);
        Mutex.Exit(loker);
        BeginRead();
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BeginRead();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help to know which object throws the exception, and where in your code it is thrown.

Comment: Which .NET framework version are you on?

Comment: I don't think you need a locking mechanism. BeginRead and the CallBack may run in different threads but not in the same time. They run one after the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need here is a synchronization method designed for asynchronous, rather than synchronous, critical sections.  You want to be able to run some code asynchronously after the code is able to take out the lock rather than making your asynchronous method use synchronous locking mechanisms.  Those synchronous mechanisms also generally expect the lock to be released from the same thread as it was taken out on; for an asynchronous operation that doesn't make sense.  `SemaphoreSlim` is specifically designed to support asynchronous synchronization.

```
private TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
private SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

public void BeginRead()
{
    semaphore.WaitAsync()
        .ContinueWith(t =>
            client.GetStream()
            .BeginRead(null, 0, 0, Read_Callback, null));
}

private void Read_Callback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    client.GetStream().EndRead(ar);

    semaphore.Release();
    BeginRead();
}
```

You also have the option of using the TPL to refactor this program rather dramatically.

To do this you'd need to create a method that generates a `Task` based on the asynchronous operation you're interested in, rather than another style of asynchrony:

```
public static Task<int> WhenRead(
    this NetworkStream stream,
    byte[] buffer,
    int offset,
    int size)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    stream.BeginRead(buffer, offset, size, result =>
    {
        tcs.TrySetResult(stream.EndRead(result));
    }, null);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

But once you have that the program becomes far easier to work with:

```
public async void BeginRead()
{
    while (true)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        int result = await client.GetStream().WhenRead(null, 0, 0);
        semaphore.Release();
        DoStuffWithResult(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is really an elegant code. Unfortunately I can't use it since I don't want to shake the code and my manager too much

Answer (score 1):

First, you've mixed the `Monitor` class with the `Mutex` class. `Mutex` doesn't have any of those static methods.

Now, what you're experiencing is the fact that you use `Monitor.Exit` inside the callback, which is called presumably called from a different thread. This doesn't work, as `Monitor.Exit` must be called from the thread owning the lock object.

Instead, you can use other locking primitives, such as a `Semaphore`, which doesn't have this requirement:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
private static readonly Semaphore Semaphore = new Semaphore(1, 1);

public void BeginRead()
{
    if (!Semaphore.WaitOne(0))
    {
        return;
    }
    client.GetStream().BeginRead(..., Read_Callback);
}

private void Read_Callback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    client.GetStream().EndRead(ar);
    Semaphore.Release();
    BeginRead();
}
```

Comment: This is removing all of the asynchrony from the program, as you're performing a blocking wait before performing the asynchronous operation.

Comment: @Servy The OP asked for a locking primitive that could deal with his situation. This doesn't remove the asynchrony from the operation, it removes the option for making multiple asynchronous requests concurrently.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It *does* remove the asynchrony.  `BeginRead` is no longer asynchronous, despite it's name.  The method will now block until all other operations are complete rather than returning immediately, as all asynchronous operations should, and then starting the asynchronous operation as soon as the lock is able to be taken out for that block.

Comment: If one request is sent to `BeginRequest`, it will run, acquire the lock and start the internal `BeginRead`, it won't block. Only if multiple calls are made, then i will block and that is a problem. But that OP wasn't asking for a refactor.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov If you assume calls are never ever made concurrently then there's no point in synchronizing the code in the first place.  The only reason to ever synchronize the code is if you plan to call it concurrently.

Comment: @Servy You're right. The OP will need to elaborate more so we can see what he needs this for.

Comment: @Servy and Yuval Itzchakov you are both right. The code that you see is a tiny part of agly designed code that I am not allowed to rewrite. Yuval solution is needed to patch a bug in bad design not even in a bad code.

Answer (score 0):

A `Mutex` cannot be acquired on one thread and release on another. It **must** be released by the thread that acquire it. A mutex owner is a *thread*.

I would strongly advice against doing anything like you try to do (hold locks during async calls). The general pattern is to lock during posting the calls and during the completion:

```
lock(something) {
   ... 
   BeginIO(...)
}


completion:

   result = endIO;
   lock(something)
   {
     ...
   }
```

Comment: Yes, this I understand that Mutex owner is a thread. I need some other class that will do the job.

Comment: In your example there possibility that 2 threads will wait in the same socket and my goal is to avoid this.

Comment: Synchronize at higher level. I can't know what your program does, but don't synchronize the *socket*. Socket completion get bits, assemble frames, dispatches received data. The dispatch is usually *the* a perfect place for synchronization. The very concept of a thread 'waiting' on a socket is wrong. It means you use async IO incorrectly. Be reactive, event driven.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use ReaderWriterLockSlim. It has IsReadLockHeld method.